# How to export traits from a separate cargo workspace github repo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, lib

I am fairly new to rust and am trying to understand how best to create re-useable shared library components. I have a github repo named **rust-libs** that is setup as a cargo workspace. The project tree for this repo looks like this:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── describable
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       ├── describable.rs
│       └── lib.rs
└── health_check
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        ├── health_check.rs
        └── lib.rs
```

where the top-level **Cargo.toml** file contains:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "describable",
    "health_check"
]
```

The **Cargo.toml** file in each member just defines the dependencies of that member and its version - e.g. **describable/Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "lib_describable"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = ["my-name <me@email.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "lib_describable"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

and **health_check/Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "lib_health_check"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = ["my-name <me@email.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
lib_describable = { path = "../describable" }

[lib]
name = "lib_health_check"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

Note that I am naming the library with a **lib_** prefix just to avoid any clashes with other rust libraries.

The **lib.rs** file in each workspace member just defines the public modules I want to export - e.g. **describable/src/lib.rs**:

```
pub mod describable;
```

The implementation for this is in **describable/src/describable.rs**:

```
pub trait Describable {
  fn describe(&self) -> String;
}
```

The implementation in **health_check/src/health_check.rs** is:

```
use lib_describable::describable::Describable;

pub trait HealthCheckable: Describable {
  fn check_health(&mut self) -> Result<(), String>;
}
```

When making any changes to a specific member, I always update its version number in its **Cargo.toml** file. CircleCI is used to automatically build this repo. If the build is successful, then the CircleCI job tags this repo with a multiple git tags (one per member in the workspace) and these tags are of the form `<member-name>_<member-version-from-its-cargo-toml>_<git-short-commit-sha>`, e.g. for the above two members it might tag the build with these tags:

```
describable_1.0.0_d2db9ff
health_check_1.0.0_d2db9ff
```

I then have a separate git repo that contains a rust binary that is built that makes use of these shared library members. The project refers to the shared library members in its **Config.toml** as follows:

```
...
[dependencies]
...
lib_describable = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/xxx/rust-libs.git", tag = "describable_1.0.0_d2db9ff" }
lib_health_check = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/xxx/rust-libs.git", tag = "health_check_1.0.0_d2db9ff" }
...
[[bin]]
name = "my-app"
path = "src/bin/main.rs"
```

**xxx** is just the obfuscated name of my github account. The file **src/bin/main.rs** in this project contains code of the form:

```
extern crate lib_describable;
extern crate lib_health_check;

use lib_describable::describable::Describable;
use lib_health_check::health_check::HealthCheckable;

pub trait MyDb: Describable + HealthCheckable {
  // some functions defined here that are not important for this issue
}

pub struct MySpecialDb { ... }

impl Describable for MySpecialDb {
  fn describe(&self) -> String {
    // returns a description of this DB
  }
}

impl HealthCheckable for MySpecialDb {
  fn check_health(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
    // performs some health check specific to this DB and returns either Ok(()) if its healthy or Err("...some error message...") if it is unhealthy
  }
}

impl MyDb for MySpecialDb { ... }
```

The problem I am finding is that the rust compiler does not seem to like the line **impl HealthCheckable for MySpecialDb** and reports an error of the form:

```
the trait bound `...::MySpecialDb: lib_describable::describable::Describable` is not satisfied

the trait `lib_describable::describable::Describable` is not implemented for `...::MySpecialDb`

note: perhaps two different versions of crate `lib_describable` are being used?rustc(E0277)
```

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here to cause this error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that cargo thinks `lib_describable(git)` is different than `lib_health_check(git) -> lib_describable(path)`, you might be able to [override depenedencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#overriding-repository-url) to get them in line

Comment: @kmdreko That section of the docs describes how to patch in other versions of a crate. I could not get that to work either with my scenario. Would really appreciate it if you could please sketch out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems this is not a supported configuration in Cargo as can be seen from the responses I got for the issue I raised here: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8956

I have therefore converted my Cargo workspace repo into a Cargo lib repo where all my libs share a single version now.